# SAM broadcaster web integration with spacial.com

Tags: internet-radio

I have SAM BROADCASTER PRO and I  want to integrate it to my website for live streaming and showing playlist.It will be a great help if I get a solution over here.

I can't write much more as I don't have much experience with it.

And one more thing it is bought from spacial.com

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) first.

Answer (score 0):

If you look the folder into which you installed Sam Broadcaster.  By default I think it goes to /program files(x86)/spacialaudio/  you will find two folders, SamHTMLweb and SamPHPweb.  Both of these can be uploaded to a web server and with a little configuration provide you with a dedicated web site for Sam Broadcaster.

If your desire is to intergrate it with an existing website than you can find code in either of these folders that you can incorporate into your existing website.